# tinyMCE posting code with script tags?

Tags: php, mysql, database, tinymce, htmlpurifier

I have created a page to create articles http://8mags.com/bored/people/
When I posted an article with script tags and other HTML tags it came out with scripts tag here is the link to generated article http://8mags.com/bored/people/stories/59b4f0c3a94d5f2637b376be6e554480.php
Is this a security threat? How can I prevent it? Here is the code that I am using

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['content'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['title'])&&!empty($_REQUEST['writer'])) {
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$writer = $_POST['writer'];
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$pure_content = $purifier->purify($content);
$entity_content = htmlentities($pure_content);
$entity_content = $mysqli->real_escape_string($entity_content);
$slashedtitle = addslashes($_POST['title']);
$slashedcontent = addslashes($_POST['content']);
$slashedwriter = addslashes($_POST['writer']);
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO stories (TITLE, WRITER, CONTENT, UPVOTE, DOWNVOTE) VALUES ('$slashedtitle', '$slashedwriter', '$slashedcontent', 0, 0)");
```

Comment: Did you write/paste the html code directly into the tinyMCE editor?

Comment: Yes I pasted it directly from my own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no security threat as far as I can see. By using HTMLPurifier all malicious code should be removed.

What happend here I suspect is that the tinyMCE editor converted your written code into HTML entities **before** the form was submitted., e.g. `<script>` was converted to `&lt;script&gt;`. Therefore the code doesn't get executed in the browser and can't be malicous.

If you want to test what happens to malicous code do it right and use a tool like Firebug to inject the code into the editor, so it can't get escaped.